# R: Using cor.test on multiple columns on a data frame

Tags: r

It know it seems like a pretty simple question, but I can't find the answer cause i'm new in R programing.
I have a df composed by a first ID column (treated and not patients) and several columns of metabolic variables.
I'm trying to write a simple script that could allow me to make a spearman correlation of the first column with all the other variables.
I've tried with the "apply" function like: apply(df,2,cor) but it does not work thus I imagine i should try to use a for loop...do you have any sugestion to how perform it?
thank you all

Comment: Something like `cor(df[,1],df[,-1])` might work but without knowing your data it's hard to know for sure. `apply(df,2,cor,x=df[,1])` might also be a solution

Comment: True...without knowing the structure of the data is hard to tell. But you might want to isolate the columns having the values, then run the      apply(df[,colsWith.Values],2,cor)

Comment: Yes guy you right i'll add an exemple sorry

Answer (score 6):

I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38558925/6447662). Following is brief summary:

Install the `corrr` package. Then, `correlate()` your data frame variables and `focus()` on your variable of choice. Here's an example using `mtcars` data frame and focusing on the correlations that `mpg` has with all other variables:

```
install.packages("corrr")  # though keep eye out for new version coming soon
library(corrr)
mtcars %>% correlate() %>% focus(mpg)


#>    rowname        mpg
#>      <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1      cyl -0.8521620
#> 2     disp -0.8475514
#> 3       hp -0.7761684
#> 4     drat  0.6811719
#> 5       wt -0.8676594
#> 6     qsec  0.4186840
#> 7       vs  0.6640389
#> 8       am  0.5998324
#> 9     gear  0.4802848
#> 10    carb -0.5509251
```

If you're not familiar with the pipe operator (`%>%`), you can read the code as:

```
focus(correlate(mtcars), mpg)
```

or

```
x <- correlate(mtcars)
focus(x, mpg)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. For which version it is availabre this package called "corrr" I can not find it for the 3.2.2

Comment: Good question - as it's a new package, it's only available for the latest version of R (3.3.1). You can find more information here: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/corrr/index.html