# Correlation between multiple variables of a data frame

Tags: r, correlation

I have a `data.frame` of 10 Variables in `R`. Lets call them `var1` `var2`...`var10`

I want to find correlation of one of `var1` with respect to
`var2`, `var3` ... `var10`

How can we do that?

`cor` function can find correlation between 2 variables at a time. By using that I had to write `cor` function for each Analysis

Comment: You could use an apply statement:
 `apply(iris[,2:4],2, function(x) cor(x, iris$Sepal.Length) )`

Comment: You can use `cor(data.frame)` which will give you a matrix of correlations between all variables. Just extract the relevant row/column from this matrix .

Comment: `cor(dat$var1, dat[c( "var2", "var3", "var4")])`. So using Philip's example, `cor(iris$Sepal.Length, iris[2:4])`

Comment: @milind kumar.  you may want to accept whichever answer worked for you. Here is how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 10):

My package `corrr`, which helps to explore correlations, has a simple solution for this. I'll use the mtcars data set as an example, and say we want to focus on the correlation of `mpg` with all other variables.

```
install.packages("corrr")  # though keep eye out for new version coming soon
library(corrr)
mtcars %>% correlate() %>% focus(mpg)


#>    rowname        mpg
#>      <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1      cyl -0.8521620
#> 2     disp -0.8475514
#> 3       hp -0.7761684
#> 4     drat  0.6811719
#> 5       wt -0.8676594
#> 6     qsec  0.4186840
#> 7       vs  0.6640389
#> 8       am  0.5998324
#> 9     gear  0.4802848
#> 10    carb -0.5509251
```

Here, `correlate()` produces a correlation data frame, and `focus()` lets you focus on the correlations of certain variables with all others.

FYI, `focus()` works similarly to `select()` from the `dplyr` package, except that it alters rows as well as columns. So if you're familiar with `select()`, you should find it easy to use `focus()`. E.g.:

```
mtcars %>% correlate() %>% focus(mpg:drat)

#>   rowname        mpg        cyl       disp         hp        drat
#>     <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1      wt -0.8676594  0.7824958  0.8879799  0.6587479 -0.71244065
#> 2    qsec  0.4186840 -0.5912421 -0.4336979 -0.7082234  0.09120476
#> 3      vs  0.6640389 -0.8108118 -0.7104159 -0.7230967  0.44027846
#> 4      am  0.5998324 -0.5226070 -0.5912270 -0.2432043  0.71271113
#> 5    gear  0.4802848 -0.4926866 -0.5555692 -0.1257043  0.69961013
#> 6    carb -0.5509251  0.5269883  0.3949769  0.7498125 -0.09078980
```

Comment: Hello, Do you know how to display the p-values from focus() ?

Comment: @Luis corrr does not compute p-values, but the question has come up before (eg this issue: https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr/issues/44).

Answer (score 4):

I think better still, you could get the correlation, not just mapped one variable to all but all variables mapped to all others. You can do that easily with just one line of code. Using the pre-installed `mtcars` datasets.

```rb
library(dplyr)

cor(select(mtcars, mpg, wt, disp, drat, qsec, hp ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use libraries Hmisc and corrplot to get correlations amongst all pairs, significance and a pretty plot like so :

```
#Your data frame (4 variables instead of 10)    
df<-data.frame(a=c(1:100),b=rpois(1:100,.2),c=rpois(1:100,.4),d=rpois(1:100,.8),e=2*c(1:100))

#setup 
library(Hmisc) 
library(corrplot)

 df<-scale(df)# normalize the data frame. This will also convert the df to a matrix.  

corr<-rcorr(df) # compute Pearson's (or spearman's corr) with rcorr from Hmisc package. I like rcorr as it allows to separately access the correlations, the # or observations and the p-value. ?rcorr is worth a read.
corr_r<-as.matrix(corr[[1]])# Access the correlation matrix. 
corr_r[,1]# subset the correlation of "a" (=var1 ) with the rest if you want.
pval<-as.matrix(corr[[3]])# get the p-values

corrplot(corr_r,method="circle",type="lower",diag=FALSE,tl.col="black",tl.cex=1,tl.offset=0.1,tl.srt=45)# plot all pairs

corrplot(corr_r,p.mat = pval,sig.level=0.05,insig = "blank",method="circle",type="lower",diag=FALSE,tl.col="black",tl.cex=1,tl.offset=0.1,tl.srt=45)# plot pairs with significance cutoff defined by "p.mat"
```